# Pre-increment and post-increment in C++ not working correctly when used as arguments

Tags: c++, post-increment, pre-increment

I came across this problem in c++ randomly. By my understanding this code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void foo(int a, int b){
    cout<<"a = "<<a;
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"b = "<<b; }

int main() {
    int i = 1;
    foo(++i,i++);

    return 0; }
```

should print out:

```
a = 2 
b = 2
```

But instead it prints out

```
a = 3
b = 1
```

How is that possible?

Comment: Who said function arguments are evaluated left to right?

Comment: Sigh, not another one of these questions... In this case, the arguments are evaluated from right to left. i = 1, then it is incremented but since you are using post increment, the original 1 is passed for b, but i is 2. Next, you use pre-increment, and pass that incremented value, which is now 3, to a.

Comment: [Order of evaluation of function arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+or+%5Bc%2B%2B11%5D+order+of+evaluation+of+function+arguments)

Comment: @StoryTeller standard did.

Comment: @SergeyA - Cite it then

Comment: Reopened, since duplicate is out of date. Will answer with latest state of the affairs.

Comment: Closed again, since there are many updated answers in the duplicate. For c++11, 14 and 17.

Comment: @SergeyA You should put that answer in the canonical and leave it closed to that.

Comment: @NathanOliver I do not see how people will get past legacy wall of text in the canonical. C++ 17 (the most important one!) down below, and I bet no more than 1 out of 10 readers gets to it.

Comment: @SergeyA That still doesn't change the fact that all the consensus on meta says that is the way it should be done.